# How to Remove JSESSION ID from URL

Tags: tomcat6

I am working with a web application in Tomcat 6 . When I copy the URL and pasted in browser ,a 'jsession' id is added to my URL . For disable this , I used

`ContextdisableURLRewriting=true` in the context.xml file in the server conf folder  and i was able to successfully tested in my localhost .

But when I moved this changes into my actual production server , the issue is still exists . I am bit confused that, why this fix not affect in my production server since this is working in my localhost.can anyone help me on this ? Or please suggest me any other solution to remove 'jseesion id' from url .

Comment: What is the server at production? different from tomcat 6?

Comment: no ,its also tomcat 6 . In my local context.xml looks like <Context disableURLRewriting="true"> and production context.xml looks like <Context useHttpOnly="true" disableURLRewriting="true">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, it is caused by difference of Tomcat version between your local and production environment. `disableURLRewriting` has been introduced since Tomcat 6.0.30.